# Python, for loop, not reseting the incrimination when calling the method

Tags: python

```
  def seekNextStation(self):
    counter = 0
    print(counter)
    for counter in range(len(self.stations)):
        counter +=1
        print(counter)
        if counter != 6:
            self.currentlyTuned = self.stations[counter]
            counter +=1
            print(counter, "in if")
        else:
            counter = 1

        return "Currently Tuned: " + self.currentlyTuned
```

The part that i am trying to get is how do i keep the incrimination when i call seekNextStation(). at the moment it will change counter to 1 return the station in index[1] then change counter to 2, but when i call it again it will reset counter to 0 and redo the same steps

Comment: You can keep a global `counter` variable if you want.  Not gonna lie, I laughed at "incrimination."  The word you want is incrementation.

Comment: Is this a method of a class? If so, you need to make `counter` a field of the class and not a local variable in the method.

Comment: Where does the 6 come from? is it `len(self.stations)`?

Comment: @OpenUserX03 lol

Comment: @JasonM.Owens it is a method and i need to put it out side the the method.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy the total stations is 6 and i put  range(len(self.stations)) because thats how i got it to spit out a station

Comment: @JoJo, It would be good practise to replace the `6` with `len(stations)` so the code doesn't break `stations` is changed later. If also makes the meaning of the code clearer

Answer (score 0):

While you can rebind the index variable of the for loop, the result lasts until the start of the next iteration. Then Python rebinds it back to the next item from the sequence you passed to the for loop

It looks like you're trying to build a complicated way to cycle through stations. This type of thing is common enough to be included in the std library

```
>>> stations = ['station1', 'station2', 'station3', 'station4', 'station5', 'station6']
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> station_gen = cycle(stations)
>>> next(station_gen)
'station1'
>>> next(station_gen)
'station2'
>>> next(station_gen)
'station3'
>>> next(station_gen)
'station4'
>>> next(station_gen)
'station5'
>>> next(station_gen)
'station6'
>>> next(station_gen)
'station1'
>>> next(station_gen)
'station2'
>>> next(station_gen)
'station3'
>>> next(station_gen)
'station4'
```